# Magento bundled product dynamic price missing (after 1.5 to 1.9 upgrade)

Tags: magento-1.9, bundled-product

I recently upgraded my magento from 1.5.x to 1.9.x (with all the security patches).

When I went to create a new bundled product, I noticed that the `Prices` tab looks different from a fresh install of magento 1.9. On the upgraded magento, I do not see the "dynamic" price option, instead I see just a singled field for `RRP`.

**Upgraded Magento**
[image]

**Fresh Magento Install**
[image]

I initially thought it was due to some module I was using, so I tried disabling local modules and it did not help, I still could not see the "dynamic price" option in bundled product creation screen.

I also tried restoring the orignal "adminhtml" theme/skin and it did not help.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Here is a list of "enabled" modules on my magento: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=Vat1En6s

Comment: I am guessing you have a custom module or override installed that is causing that behavior

Comment: I don't think so. I only used the database and used fresh magento 1.9 installation file. So, none of the old site's code was brought with the upgrade.

Comment: I do think so. The old database contains all modifications from extensions you had in the old site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that price attribute in Magento 1.5 does not have 'Bundle Product' selected by default under the 'Apply to' section as bundle products do not exist in that version. When the version is updated, it is not automatically enabled, so has to be selected manually.

[image: Select new product types]